# pyTesseract not outputing text from image

Tags: python, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

maybe someone could help me! When I run the following code

import pytesseract
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL import Image
import PIL

```
file = Image.open('/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.0/share/tessdata/cap.png')
we_will = pytesseract.image_to_string(file)
print(we_will)
```

all that gets outputed is:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

which is no help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `we_will` is the empty string. Try printing `repr(we_will)` to understand this idea more clearly.

IIRC, PyTesseract does this when it can't figure out what the text is inside the image. You can get the best results for a cropped image with a single-color background.

Comment: Thank you, i was attempting to use pyTesseract to break a captcha but that was pointless!